# Vue 2 updates and prints after loading the page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, printing, printing-web-page

I use Vue 2.5, I update the data after the created function fetch API returns, and execute `window.print()` in the updated function.

It still shows blank.

#### created function

```js
created() {
  axios.get(`/api/pickUp/preview`, {
    params: {
      code,
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    this.preview = true;
    this.shipment = res.data.data.shipments;
    this.selectedShipment = res.data.data.shipments;
    this.price = res.data.data.price;
  });
},
```

#### updated function

```js
updated() {
  if(this.preview) {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      window.print();
    });
  }
},
```

#### [Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLzTp.png)

#### [In fact, the page has information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7ZBV.png)

I tried using `setTimeout` or executing `$nextTick` directly at the bottom of the created function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you can try to make this work. Since there's no working jsFiddle for this problem, I can only suggest you try these.

- Try converting the created hook into an async function and await the axios call.

```
    async created() {
        await axios.get(`/api/pickUp/${no}/preview`, {
        params: {
          code,
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        this.preview = true;
        this.shipment = res.data.data.shipments;
        this.selectedShipment = res.data.data.shipments;
        this.price = res.data.data.price;
      });
```

- Try moving the updated hook code inside .then in created hook.

```
    async created() {
      await axios.get(`/api/pickUp/${no}/preview`, {
        params: {
          code,
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        this.preview = true;
        this.shipment = res.data.data.shipments;
        this.selectedShipment = res.data.data.shipments;
        this.price = res.data.data.price;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
        window.print();
        });
      });
    },
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, same result.

Comment: Have you tried using the beforeCreate hook?

Comment: Yes... still doesn't work.

Comment: Your data doesn't even render in the template or it just doesn't show in the picture?

Comment: Finally we solved the problem with Laravel SSR. thank you for your help.